# Could not load type 'xxx' in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In `VS 2010, asp.net,` i received a partial project i.e. few modules with all markup and code behind files and for others will be referred from the `assembly` in `bin` folder. It worked properly without any issues. After sometime, i got remaining `markup` and code behind files for others and then i removed the 'assembly' from `bin`. When i run the application, i got `Could not load type 'xxx'` error. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the reference of assembly before deleting it, after removing reference and deleting assembly compile it. After sussessful compilation try to get the page.

Make sure the assembly is no more required as assemblies could be accessed through reflection library without reference.

Answer (score 1):

You've not been provided with all the markup and code behind files compared to the original DLL or they differ somehow from those compiled to produce the DLL. In particular the 'xxx' class is the culprit. You'd expect to find:

```
xxx.aspx
xxx.aspx.designer.vb / xxx.aspx.design.cs
xxx.aspx.vb / xxx.aspx.cs
```

(Depending on whether you're using VB or C#).

It could also be a namespace issue, check your Project settings and make sure that the provided markup/code behinds align with your root namespace.